# jQuery | Position div at finger location when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My div (#mouse) is positioned at the mouse on mousemove. I want to position it at a users finger on mobile. The problem is that when the user scrolls, it is not updating the div's css.

Here is the code :

```
$(window).on("mousemove tap taphold swipe scrollstart scroll", function (e) {
    $("#mouse").css({
        left: e.pageX + "px",
        top: e.pageY + 'px'
    });
});
```

The mouse div only gets positioned when touching with finger.

Comment: Does the `#mouse` div have css position set to fixed or absolute or are you using the default value?

Comment: @FemiOladeji It is set to absolute.